# How to os.chdir into a directory previously made through os.path.join within loop?

Tags: python, ssl, grpc

I am writing code that creates grpc ssl certificates for services and places them in directories which are made through scanning two json files.

Part of this code is to loop over a json and create directories based on the names of the services listed in it, within a loop. I would like to use the use the chdir function to cd into the directory recently created within each loop iteration in order to run ssl script function, called "cert_create".

I will list the sample code below

```
for data in servicesUsedJson:
    pwd = os.getcwd()
    service = data.get("service")
    used = data.get("services_used")
    if service is None or used is None:
        raise ValueError("Missing information")
    for u in used:
        os.path.join(pwd, "certs", service, u)
        # this is where I would like to add os.chdir into the directory created above in order to run the function below 
        cert_create(str(serviceIp[u])))
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of `os.path.join()` to a variable. Then you can use that as the argument to `os.chdir()`

Comment: Where are you creating the directory?

Comment: The comment mentions "the directory created above", where is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    path = os.path.join(pwd, "certs", service, u)  # Save path to variable
    if not os.path.exists(path):  # Create directory if does not exist
        os.mkdir(path)  

    os.chdir(path)  # Change directory
except OSError:
    print ("Failed.")
```